# I cant create if statement with && and ||

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statement like this:

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@"string"] && myint == 3 || myint == 2) {...}
```

What that basically is, it's making sure the `strings` are equal. Then, either `myint` can be equal to 2 or 3.

When I try doing that, I get an error saying `'&&' withing '||'`. It suggest putting parenthesis around the `&&` statement like this:

```
if (([myString isEqualToString:@"string"] && myint == 3) || myint == 2)
```

My question is, why can't I do it without the parenthesis. And what do the parenthesis do?

Comment: Well, the suggestion is wrong. You'd probably want `if ([myString isEqualToString:@"string"] && (myint == 3 || myint == 2))`. Note that the suggested rewriting is equivalent to your current code without parens because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`..

Comment: I'm guessing you're not getting an *error*, but rather a *warning* that parentheses are strongly recommended to assure you get the expected order of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a warning, and in your case the warning was excellent, because your code wouldn't have done what you wanted to do.

According to the rules of the C, C++ and Objective-C languages (and others),

```
if (a && b || c)
```

means: Do something if both a and b are true, or if c is true. That's not what you meant; what you wanted was: Do something if a is true, and also one of b and c is true. To do that you write

```
if (a && (b || c))
```

The parentheses group things together. && is stronger than || which means if you have no parentheses, like a && b || c, then the && groups a and b together. The result is the same as (a && b) || c, but not a && (b || c).

Objective-C often gives warnings for code that is technically legal, but might not be what you intended. This was one case and actually, the code didn't do what you intended. What the compiler was telling you: If you write if (a && b || c) then it is the same as if ((a && b) || c), but in the latter case the compiler is sure that you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what you want is

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@"string"] && (myint == 3 || myint == 2))
```

The parentheses do what they always do: they determine the order of operations, rather than leaving it to the priority of the operators (which you are unlikely to know).